# How to compile C++ on Elementary OS code editor?

Tags: ide

I just installed Elementary OS to program mainly because of its editor simplicity. However I don't know how to transform it into an IDE for C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: https://quickfever.com/how-to-setup-c-plus-plus-development-environment-in-linux/. Elementary OS is a derivative of Ubuntu so you may have success with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to compile via CLI (Terminal), or use an IDE that's integrated with C++. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux

Answer (score 0):

In the Code app's settings, enable the terminal view. After that, you can freely use can compile your C++ code in the terminal using the CLI. The `gcc` command for the GCC compiler should be available for you to use, out of the box.

If you wanted something that wanted a more extensible solution with plugins that you download to enable more functionality, I think that [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) are better options.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "terminal extension" on elementary code also you can run the following command:

```
gcc -o test testfile.cpp
```

This can create an executable called `test`.

Hope this can help.